# Keep getting "Unexpected end of JSON input" when calling spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I'm running this JS on a hosted service which wraps APIs in nodeJS libs, but I think it's pretty transparent:

```
var a=[{
   range: 'A1',
   values: [['Total issues',issues.length,'Last updated',new Date()]]
 },{
   range: 'A2',
   values: [['Number','Title','State']]
 }]
for(let x=0;x<issues.length;++x) {
  let i = issues[x];
  let id = i.number;
  a[a.length] = {
   range: 'A'+ (issues.length+1),
   values: [[i.number,i.title,i.state]]
 }
}

await google_sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
  spreadsheetId: input.sheet_id,
  body : { 
    data : a,
    valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED'
  }
}, context);
```

When I run this the target sheet gets the first two rows updated with the static text, but nothing else (`issues` is result of calling GitHub API and works fine) - and I get the error in the title.

When I called `update` for each issue instead of `batchUpdate` it worked but was slow and ran into API call limits.

I think I even had one case where the sheet *was* properly updated but I still got the error.

I've yet to figure out how to see the JSON emitted from this 3rd-party service, can anyone see an error in my code, or tell me if I can retrieve the JSON Google received?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about ``issues``, in your script, I think that if ``issues.length`` is not changed, all ``range`` except for the initial ``a`` is the same value. By this, all values are overwritten, and the value of last element is left. Is this related to your issue? If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: I agree with @tanaike.. looks like `issues.length+1` should be replaced with the number of elements in the array `a`. More simply, you could use `map` to convert `issues` to the associated `ValueRange` array, then `unshift` the headers.

Comment: Oh, yeah. That `issues.length` thing is a bug but I don't see it makes the JSON structurally different... It would just give the wrong results? I.e. it's a big if spot once the code worked... Or have I missed something?

Comment: @Mr. Boy I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. And I couldn't notice your reply. For example, how about changing the request body or method? For changing the request body, all values are put in one batch. For changing the method, it uses spreadsheets.values.update. And it uses both. I'm not sure about your environment. So this proposal is my speculation. I'm sorry for this situation.

Comment: I'm now seeing the situation after some tweaks, I get the error but it is seemingly working correctly. Very odd! Thanks for your suggestion